# While loop not working with x <=num

Tags: php, html

```
$x = 1;

$num = 15;

while($x <= $num) {
   $res = '[TR][TD="align: left"]'.$x.'[/TD][TD="align: left"][/TD][/TR]';
   $x++;
} 

echo $res;
```

That's my code but it only shows the following when I try it:
[TR][TD="align: left"]15[/TD][TD="align: left"][/TD][/TR]

It should show that but instead of only 15 it should be 1-15 inclusive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep setting `$res` to a new value rather than appending to it. Using `$res .= 'something';` is like saying `$res = $res . 'something';`. Doing this will allow you to keep the previous value of `$res` and appending more to the end of it.

```
$x = 1;
$num = 15;
$res = '';

while($x <= $num) {
   $res .= '[TR][TD="align: left"]'.$x.'[/TD][TD="align: left"][/TD][/TR]';
   $x++;
} 

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = 1;

$num = 15;

while($x <= $num) {
   $res = '[TR][TD="align: left"]'.$x.'[/TD][TD="align: left"][/TD][/TR]';
   $x++;
   echo $res;
}
```

Put `echo $res;` inside the loop, otherwise it will echo just the `$res` from the last loop cycle instead of all 15 times.

Comment: This does work and I did upvote it, yet the other method given can access `$res` anywhere within a file, as opposed to having it confined/accessible only in the loop. Your answer does work though.

Comment: Works but as Fred said, accessing the varialbe outside the loop makes it much easier to work with :)